# Planes in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: vector-spaces

I know a possible subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ is this one:

$ U = \{ x \in \mathbb R | x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0 \}$

My math book writes that this would be a plane in $\mathbb R^3$ that goes through $(0,0,0)$. This statement seems to imply that $U$ is a single plane with a specific orientation in $\mathbb R^3$. But I am not so certain that this is correct.

**Question 1:** Is $U$ now the set of ALL planes which go through the origin $(0,0,0)$, or is $U$ a SINGLE plane with a well defined orientation inside $\mathbb R^3$?

**I would argue like this:** It is the set of all planes that go through the origin, because if we take three vectors (-2, 2, 0), (2, 0, -2), (3, 5, -8), then the last one cannot be created through a linear combination of the first two, and so its not on the plane that is formed by the first two vectors.

But I am currently quite uncertain if that is correct.

Are there any tools (preferably open source), that can visualize planes and vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ so I can experiment with this a litte?

Comment: What about $2.5\cdot (-2,2,0)+4\cdot(2,0,-2)=(-5,5,0)+(8,0,-8)=(3,5,-8)$?

Comment: $U$ is the *unique* plane containing the origin which is orthogonal to the vector $(1,1,1)$.  As for tools you can try WolframAlpha or GeoGebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just a single plane which passes throguh the origin.

We can see this by parameterizing the points of $U$ with the variables $x_1$ and $x_2$. Every point of $U$ can be written as $(x_1,x_2,-x_1-x_2)$; this vector can be decomposed in the following manner,

$$ (x_1,x_2,-x_1-x_2) = x_1 (1,0,-1) + x_2 (0,1,-1), $$

which demonstrates that $U$ is a two dimensional vector space.